# Strange behavior re-runing java application in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, unix, resources, daemon

Unix daemon runs a script a loop, the script calls a java program: java {java_args} myClas.jar

The java program is heavy program with multiple threads.

The problem is very strange: First execution works as expected. 
But the second execution is stuck some where and I can't find a reason (very hard to debug this).

Is there a possibility that when first execution is finished there are still not-cleaned resources or threads left from this execution?

If yes, is it possible to clean and kill everything right after process completes?

Comment: what is 'stuck somewhere'? It just stops executing?

Comment: the, loop is "stuck" in second execution of the java program. It stuck somewhere there...

Answer (score 1):

If by resources, you mean threads, then no. When the VM shuts down, everything on the heap, all threads, objects and monitors are disposed of. However if you're depending on the existence/absence of a file for locking or something similar, a deadlock is possible. Also, is it possible that the first process is still running when you launch the second one?

If your java process is stuck on the second run, you can attach [`jvisualvm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) to it and should be able to figure out where it's stuck.

Comment: I don't think it possible that second lunch starts before the first one finishes, because: 'java myjar.jar' is blocking...

Comment: Yes the process is using files, but files exists in the env (process using to read same files and to write them)

Comment: Are the threads daemon threads? If not & they haven't finished, the program will not exit (unless you've used System.exit)

Comment: @user992484, I exit with System.exit(0)